# Amazon s3: How to grant only to user who view under my website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web, storage

When I looked at the console we can grant user either everyone, private or by authenticated user. Can I set the permission only for the user who viewing my website e.g.
 I have a website called www.abc.com. The photo need to set a permission that only user who use this www.abc.com site in order to view the bucket of photos?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of bucket policy to archive this. See the example "Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer" here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Thanks for replied. Yes i have just added a policy. I have setup my domain server as an example: photo.domainName.com which is the same as the bucket name in amazon. Now i can typed photo.domainName.com on browser to access the object but it can be done before I put policy in. After added the policy, I still have cross origin error when dealing with canvas in the html

Comment: It's the CORS problem, and does not relevant to your original question. You should ask it in another question.